# Scala sbt tests: "No configuration setting found for key 'akka'" after switching to Java 11

Tags: scala, sbt, akka, akka-actor

After switching to Java 11, sbt tests started to fail with the exception "No configuration setting found for key 'akka'". We are using sbt assembly plugin on the project but since the tests are run not inside jar but using sbt <module_name>/test, looks like there are some issues with building test resources/paths.

List of things I did:

1. Added concat MergeStrategy for 'reference.conf' file. Jar that is assembled has all files inside and there are no issues with that, so it is only a test step issue.
2. Checked class path for tests using 'export <module_name>/test:fullClasspath' in sbt before and after migrating to Java 11. They are the same.

Everything else except of a test where I create actor system works good.
Code that creates actor system:

```scala
object MyObjectTest extends AsyncFunSuite {
  private implicit val system: ActorSystem = ActorSystem("MyActorSystem")
  private implicit val ex: ExecutionContext = system.dispatcher
}
```

At the moment I do not have any ideas what should I check next, so any suggestions would be appreciated.

P.S. running tests inside IDEA works good, but we have CI/CD job that runs tests using sbt test command.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28365000/no-configuration-setting-found-for-key-akka

Comment: Please provide a [reproduction](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) i.e. your `build.sbt` etc. along with a sample test throwing `No configuration setting found for key 'akka'`

Comment: @DmytroMitin, I already have this line and my jar build works good. The issue is with running sbt test command.

Comment: Would you prepare MCVE?

Comment: I am working on it at the moment

Comment: @DmytroMitin thanks for you time and help, I was not been able to create a reproduction, but I solved the original issue. Please take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there are some issues when you are using sbt + Java 11. I tried to reproduce this error using a small project with the same configuration but was not been able to do it. However, the issue was fixed using the following option in sbt:

```
Test / fork := true
```

According to sbt documentation, this property creates a separate JVM for running all tests. I think all configurations have been set up correctly for another JVM.

Hope this answer will help someone in future.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you didn't need `Test / fork := true` in older versions of Java but need this in Java 11?

Comment: yes, looks like the issue with configuration when tests are running in the same JVM.